# Validate whether foreign key exists if not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, foreign-keys, null

I have a many-to-one relationship defined in Rails 4:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

How do I check, that the `:user` key exists if it is set?

The following correctly checks, that the key exists but does not allow for `nil? values:

```
  validates :user, presence: true
```

The following allows any value, even non-existing IDs:

```
  validates :user, presence: true, allow_nil: true
```

How do you do such kind of validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the before_save callback to check that the user is valid if it is supplied:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user    

  before_save: :validate_user unless: Proc.new { |event| event.user.nil? }

  private
    def validate_user
      if User.where(id: user_id).empty?
        errors[:user] << "must be valid"
      end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You must keep the presence validation in `Event` and add in `User` model:

```
has_many :events, inverse_of: :user
```

Answer (score 1):

Just faced this problem and here are the 2 solutions

1.

```
validates :user, presence: true, if: 'user_id.present?'
```

2.

. https://github.com/perfectline/validates_existence gem

can be used like this

```
validates : user, existence: { allow_nil: true, both: false }
```

`both` option is for the error messages: `false` will show 1 error(association only), `true` will show 2 errors (association and foreign key)